# array_push() with key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array to which I want to add a value.

I'm trying to achieve that using `array_push()` to no avail.

Below is my code:

```
$data = array(
    "dog" => "cat"
);

array_push($data['cat'], 'wagon');
```

What I want to achieve is to add *cat* as a key to the `$data` array with *wagon* as value so as to access it as in the snippet below:

```
echo $data['cat']; // the expected output is: wagon
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

So what about having:

```
$data['cat']='wagon';
```

Comment: Warning: `$a['123'] = 456;` - string '123' is converted to integer key 123.

Comment: For integer keys you don't want to wrap them into quotes / string.

Comment: Not necessarily. If some other keys are strings like '123a' it could be desired to preserve string keys for all items.

Answer (score 60):

If you need to add multiple key=>value, then try this.

```
$data = array_merge($data, array("cat"=>"wagon","foo"=>"baar"));
```

Comment: Could also use a loop for that.

Comment: A loop does not help.  If you want to push values with a duplicate key name, you *must* use `array_merge`.

Comment: When merging two associative arrays, array union syntax can be used `+`.  More concisely, the array union assignment operator `+=`.

Answer (score 44):

```
$data['cat'] = 'wagon';
```

That's all you need to add the key and value to the array.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use array_push() function, you can assign new value with new key directly to the array like..

```
$array = array("color1"=>"red", "color2"=>"blue");
$array['color3']='green';
print_r($array);


Output:

   Array(
     [color1] => red
     [color2] => blue
     [color3] => green
   )
```

Comment: You should also highlight what's the exact difference, here you used = instead of , for OP

Comment: This code is wrong.  array_push takes two parameters, and you will be getting a warning about the fact you're using it wrong with the result that the call to array_push does nothing.   What the second line of your code is actually doing is simply `$array['color3']='green'`.  That's exactly what @dusoft did above.  Your code is just an obfuscation of that solution.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you for showing my mistake, I have changed my answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

For Example:

```
$data = array('firstKey' => 'firstValue', 'secondKey' => 'secondValue');
```

For changing key value:

```
$data['firstKey'] = 'changedValue'; 
//this will change value of firstKey because firstkey is available in array
```

> output:
>
> Array ( [firstKey] => changedValue [secondKey] => secondValue )

For adding new key value pair:

```
$data['newKey'] = 'newValue'; 
//this will add new key and value because newKey is not available in array
```

> output:
>
> Array ( [firstKey] => firstValue [secondKey] => secondValue [newKey]
>   => newValue )

Answer (score 5):

Array['key'] = value;

```
$data['cat'] = 'wagon';
```

This is what you need.
No need to use array_push() function for this.
Some time the problem is very simple and we think in complex way :) .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = ['name' => 'Bilal', 'education' => 'CS']; 
$data['business'] = 'IT';  //append new value with key in array
print_r($data);
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Bilal
    [education] => CS
    [business] => IT
)
```

Answer (score -4):

Just do that:

```
$data = [
    "dog" => "cat"
];

array_push($data, ['cat' => 'wagon']);
```

*In php 7 and higher, array is creating using [], not ()

Comment: Two problems: `array_push` adds its 2nd+ parameters as new values (not key-value pairings as `array_merge` does), and PHP 7 happily accepts the `array()` array syntax (as well as the shorthand `[]` syntax)