# jQuery dataTables with Codeigniter and sAjaxSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using dataTables with Codeigniter and I have a problem. I am getting a message:

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

and a result is `{"aaData":null}`

I want to get something like this: `{ "aaData": [ ["test","test","test"] ] }`

Code:

```
$result =  $this->lol_model->get();

//result = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [test] => 12345  [test2] => 1842 07 03 [test3] => lol ) )     

 $aaData = array();    
 foreach($result as $row) {
            array_push($json["aaData"],array(
                $row->test,
                $row->test2,
                $row->test3
         ));
        }
  echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Where is the $json variable declared and how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the key '["aaData"]' when using array_push. However, you can use:

```
$json["aaData"]=array(
            $row->test,
            $row->test2,
            $row->test3
     );
```

See this post also:
[array_push() with key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355072/array-push-with-key-value-pair)