# How can i add key value pair in multidimentional array without add index in php

Tags: php, sugarcrm

How can i add key value pair in multi-dimentional array without index in php

ex:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']=array (
  '192.168.1.51' => 'server1',
  // i have to add key and value pair here just like above
);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: probably your solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355072/array-push-with-key-value-pair

Comment: What do you mean "without index"? Isn't the key equivalent to an index?

Comment: $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['new_index']="newVal"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i write key value pair in array in another php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312874/how-can-i-write-key-value-pair-in-array-in-another-php-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['10.0.0.1'] = 'server2';
```

Comment: @Floris: if i put 2 text box for key and value than this key value pair should write over commented part.
How can i do that.



$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']=array (
  '192.168.1.51' => 'server1',
  // i have to add key and value pair here 
);

Answer (score 0):

the code above is

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['192.168.1.51'] = 'server1';
```

so do this

two examples of how to add two your array

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['152.124.25.25'] = 'server x'; 
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['152.100.25.25'] = 'server r';
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']=array ( '192.168.1.51' => 'server1', '152.100.25.25' => 'server x' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply..
that is what i need..
I have one more quetion.
how can i write this array in file

i need this in following pattern in php file :
//output file
xyz.php
<?php

$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']=array (
  '192.168.1.51' => 'server1',
  // i have to add key and value pair here just like above
);
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can add one by one as below :

$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['192.168.1.51'] = 'server1';

$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['192.168.1.52'] = 'server2';..... and so on..

Or

You can use foreach to add all at a time as below :

$array_server_ips = array(

'192.168.1.51'=>'server1',
'192.168.1.52'=>'server2',
'192.168.1.53'=>'server3',
'192.168.1.54'=>'server4',
'192.168.1.55'=>'server5',
'192.168.1.56'=>'server6',
'192.168.1.57'=>'server7'

);

foreach($array_server_ips as $key=>$value){

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list'][$key] = $value;
```

}