# How can i write key value pair in array in another php file

Tags: php, sugarcrm

i have one phpfile let,xyz.php and from this file i have to update another phpfile let its name,abc.php

how can i do this to achieve my desired output.

**xyz.php**

```
<?php    

//need code for update $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list'] array present in xyz.php
?>
```

**abc.php**

```
$GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']=array (
  '192.168.1.51' => 'server1',
  // i have to add key and value pair here just like above from xyz.php
);
?>
```

Comment: Does `abc.php` only contain that array, or does it contain other things ? Also why don't you use a proper format for storing data ? Think about a database for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add key value pair in multidimentional array without add index in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296992/how-can-i-add-key-value-pair-in-multidimentional-array-without-add-index-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Within `xyz.php`, use `require` or `include` to access the variables defined in `abc.php`

```
<?php
require 'abc.php';
echo $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['ip_list']['192.168.1.51']; // "server1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable $_GLOBAL is not necessary. You can also use:

```
 return array();
```

and

```
$data = require '../path/to/my/file.php';
```