# array_push confusion adding extra content

Tags: php

I am trying to add some information to an array that I am working on. I found some information on this site that has allowed me to do it ( [array_push() with key value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355072/array-push-with-key-value-pair) ) but I am getting the information in the array twice and I don't understand why.

here is my array

```
array_push($networks[0], $networks[0]['class']='fa fa-facebook');
print_r($networks);


        array(4) {
[0]=>
array(5) {
["name"]=>
string(1) "3"
["url"]=>
string(14) "facebook.com/#"
["icon_title"]=>
string(8) "facebook"
["class"]=>
string(14) "fa fa-facebook"
[0]=>
string(14) "fa fa-facebook"
}
```

here is what I want to get

```
        array(4) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
["name"]=>
string(1) "3"
["url"]=>
string(14) "facebook.com/#"
["icon_title"]=>
string(8) "facebook"
["class"]=>
string(14) "fa fa-facebook"
}
```

as you can see. The array_push is adding a second string to the end with the fa fa-facebook info. I don't wan that there. Just the last bit should be there.

```
 ["class"]=> string(14) "fa fa-facebook"
```

Comment: Why are you using `array_push` at all?

Comment: do you have a better suggestion

Comment: Yeah: "*The array_push is adding a second string to the end with the fa fa-facebook info.*" So my suggestion is: Don't use `array_push`. What is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is that as part of your `array_push()` your actually doing the assignment you need.

```
array_push($networks[0], $networks[0]['class']='fa fa-facebook');
```

So this is doing an assignment...

```
$networks[0]['class']='fa fa-facebook'
```

And then the result (the value of the assignment) is being added to the array.

So just use

```
 $networks[0]['class']='fa fa-facebook';
 print_r($networks);
```